# Firefox extension SDK: how to access address bar

Tags: firefox, sdk, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, address-bar

How can I access the address bar of Firefox inside an extension using the SDK? I want to do the following:

- Listen to events that the URL in the address bar was changed by the user, i.e. for every single key stroke, copy&pastes, etc.
- Add entries to the URL dropdown list of the address bar, based on the current URL in the address bar.

This feature is intended for an online bookmark manager application. We would like to give the users the possibility to access the bookmarks stored in our app using the normal firefox address bar.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure but I think the SDK doesn't have a module for that. But it can be done accessing XPCOM services and objects. Take a look at:

- https://github.com/ajitk/omnibar
- https://github.com/Quicksaver/Omnibar-Plus
- https://github.com/autonome/Jetpack-Modules/blob/master/awesomebar.js